# Nodejs local version vs project version

Tags: node.js

If I have a Nodejs project handed to me with the package.json specifying the version "latest" of node (which at the time of this post is Node 17), would there be an issue if my local version is node 14?

Also when I perform "npm install" I don't see any errors come back, but when I check my node version with "node -v" in the project space it still indicates node 14, but in the package-lock.json I see mentions of Node 17.

Anyone experienced in this area able to offer insight to this?

Comment: could you add your package.json?

Comment: Are you using [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#node-version-manager---) by any chance?

Comment: It depends. Lots of parts of node are backwards compatible, but there are also plenty of areas that are not. If you project uses libraries that require Node 17, or writes code that uses features only present in Node 17 and higher, then Node 14 wouldn't be adequate. If you didn't get any errors on install, then there is a good chance the project will run fine on Node 14. Again, no guarantees, you'd have to investigate the actual code you are running yourself.

Comment: I can't add the package.json right now but essentially it's something like "dependencies": {
    ...
    "node": "latest",
  }. 
I'm not using nvm, but I have heard of nvm being able to switch between node versions. I'm worried that the "latest" tag will keep pulling the latest version and slow me down in development trying to play catch up with my local to match whichever the project requires